# The voltage on unclosed conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, voltage, conductors

There are an unclosed conductor, and two magnets that situated, as shown on the picture. Is there voltage between conductor's ends?

[image]

Comment: Yes, albeit infinitesimal - and it would not be measurable in a static condition, because any probes placed at each end would also be subject to the effect of the magnets and there would be no flow of current. The current would only flow when the magnets were moved (either to apply them or remove them).

Comment: @Steve, ok, if I will just change sides of magnets, will be there an (alternating?) current?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: @АртурКлочко, yes, a current will flow *in principle* if you move the magnets.

Comment: @Steve, so if I paste there a lamp, it, *in principle* should glow?

Comment: Is the conductor just a cylindrical  wire on the same axis as the permanent wires?

Comment: @АртурКлочко, it is very unlikely that your setup would have enough strength to emit any light. It's such an unconventional setup that I'm scratching my head. The way I conceive it, you basically have the wire acting as a very weak (and totally unconventional) capacitor, and the magnets charging it (with energy stored from the force needed to move the magnets in relation to the wire). But I can't see how it would be sensible to talk about measurable effects like driving a light bulb.

Comment: @Steve, I'm understanding that the power will be weak. I'm asking , will be there a current(any power) at time, when magnets comes to ends of wire?

Comment: @freecharly, can't understand what do you mean. Conductor, I mean, it is a wire, for example

Comment: @АртурКлочко - Artur, a metal wire is normally a conductor of cylindrical form and with finite diameter. I wanted to know the exact geometrical shape of the conductor and of the magnets.  The picture could also indicate the cross section of a metal  sheet.

Comment: @АртурКлочко - Artur, why do you ask this question? Do you have any reason to believe or suspicion that there could be a voltage between the ends of the wire?

Comment: @freecharly, I'm just trying to understand electromagnetism. I wrote below, that definition says, that  *the voltage - is a work that does the electric field to move charges*. Here it is, so it is a voltage. Yes?

Comment: @АртурКлочко - Artur, in this static case and the absence of a time changing magnetic field, there can be no voltage between the ends of the metal. Even if there was an initial voltage, charges would move to the ends of the wire so that inside the wire the electric field and thus the voltage between the ends would be zero.

Answer (score 1):

If the magnets are not moving with respect to the conductor, or the wire moving with respect to the magnets, there will be no voltage between the ends of the conductor.

Comment: But, as definition says, voltage - is a difference of potentials, and in the picture I have pinned, it is. And, as another definition says, voltage - is a work that does the electric field to move charges. Electric field is the same as magnetic field, so, my picture shouldn't be wrong. Yeah, I understand, that there is no current, but in the moment, when magnets comes to ends of wire electrons should move(come to north, and run away from south at the same time), so at this time interval there should be a current. No?

Comment: @ Artur - Are the magnets also charged electrically? What do the plus and minus signs signify in the picture? I assumed they indicate the polarity of the permanent magnets.

Comment: No they don't charged electrically. Plus and minus means north and south

Comment: Conductor in english meaning, as far as I understand, is a material, that provides current. Metals are conductors. Wire consist of metal. Wire is conductor. In my illustration it's a simple solid wire

Comment: @Artur - And it is not a "perfect conductor" (superconductor)? The conductivity is finite, not infinite?

Comment: Of course, just a simple wire